# How do I specify a specific CMake target as a dependency?

Tags: cmake

Our CMake project, hosted on GitHub, has a CMake git submodule as a dependency. The file structure, then, is roughly:

```
project/
  CMakeLists.txt
  extern/
    big_lib/
      CMakeLists.txt
        include/
          *.hpp
        static/
          CMakeLists.txt
        shared/
          CMakeLists.txt
```

We have authorship of both `project` and `big_lib`.

The top level `CMakeLists.txt` for `project` includes something like:

```
add_subdirectory(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/big_lib)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} big_lib::static)
```

`big_lib::static` is a library we don't install/publish; it's not specified as such in the `big_lib` configuration, it's for internal consumption only - namely for tests. We deliver a client facing shared library, but the shared library is not appropriate for `project`.

This is why `ExternalProject_Add` may not be the most appropriate solution for satisfying our dependency - as it is my understanding installing the dependency in the build directory won't install the specific build target we need. Also, I haven't had luck getting it to work yet.

What I've also noticed is that we're building all targets in `big_lib`, of which there are hundreds - mostly tests, and that shared library I don't want or need. I suspect this is because we're including the entire library from it's base directory.

I've tried:

```
add_subdirectory(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/big_lib/static)
```

But it seems there's configuration from the `big_lib` base directory that now goes unspecified, which is why I'm including the base directory in `project` instead of this.

So my questions are:

- Is there a better way to specify the static build target so only that gets built?
- Is there a better way to organize the configuration of `big_lib` so I can add only the static library as the dependency folder, and not duplicate configuration from the base directory between static and shared?
- What options am I not aware of? Maybe I should use ExternalProject_Add and specify some sort of custom build command where I issue just the static lib as the build target and install target, and then link against that artifact?

Comment: You are right that ExternalProject doesn't give you access to the *targets* of the `big_lib`. But I see no problems in `add_subdirectory(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/big_lib)` approach. "Is there a better way to specify the static build target so only that gets built?" - Just add `option()`-s  to your `big_lib`, so it could be configured to build only a static library, or shared library, or both.

Comment: @Tsyvarev you should have written your comment as an answer, it's perfectly reasonable. I did see an example of this when searching SO for a solution. It's probably what I'm going to end up doing. I just wish CMake was a bit smarter than this.